# QT : cannot call member without object when I have a virtual function

Tags: c++, qt

I'm calling since another function in QT

My virtual function from calendar.h:

```
virtual string whatDay(string){ return "";}
```

My function from calendarGregorian.h:

```
string whatDay(string)
```

And my function on_whatDayButton_clicked() from mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_whatDayButton_clicked()
{
    QString whatDayString;
    string getDay;
    whatDayString = ui->lineGetDay->text();
    string day = whatDayString.toUtf8().constData();
    getDay = calendarGregorian::whatDay(day);

}
```

But, when I'm compiling.. it show me this error:

error: cannot call member function 'virtual std::string calendarGregorian::whatDay(std::string)' without object
     getDay = calendarGregorian::whatDay(day);
                                            ^

Please.. I need help

Comment: What don't you understand? Member functions need an object to be called on (e.g. `some_calendar.whatDay(day)`).

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing `virtual` and `static`? The former is needed for subclassing and the latter to call member functions who do not require an object.

Comment: I'm calling the function directly from my class calendarGregorian, I don't create any object some_calendar

Comment: I already trying with static.. the same problem

Comment: If you are calling the function from within the class you should probably use `getDay = this->calendarGregorian::whatDay(day);`. But the function you showed us is in the class `MainWindow` and not `calendar` or `calendarGregorian`

Comment: "I'm calling the function directly from my class calendarGregorian, I don't create any object some_calendar". That's exactly your problem. You must have an object.

Comment: "I already trying with static.." You are not trying correctly. The function must be declared static *in calendarGregorian*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot call member function without object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127738/cannot-call-member-function-without-object)

Answer (score 1):

calendar.h:

```
static string whatDay(string){ return "";}
```

calendarGregorian.h:

```
class CalendarGregorian: Calendar{
public:
    static int superCalculationFactor = 276485;
    int notSoGood;
    static string whatDay(string)
    {
        //do the formatting using superCalculationFactor
        //you can't use notSoGood!
        return result;
    }
}
```

that way you don't need an object to call the function. The problem here was that methods need objects to be called on while static functions can be called without an object.

But if you go this way, don't forget that you have only access to static class variables, and not at object variables.

Comment: I already tried that and I don't have success and my function it's:  http://ur1.ca/h566i

Comment: @user17629 and what error do you get when you make them both static, `calendarGregorian::whatDay()` and `calendar::whatDay()`?