# changing default value for class::variable without object

Tags: c++, function, class, namespaces

I receive an error that I cannot set delimiter without object. I am not sure where I went wrong.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
using namespace sd;

int main() {
    Utilities::setDelimiter(',');
    return 0;
}
```

**Utilities.h**

```cpp
namespace sd {
    class Utilities {

        static char m_delimiter;

        public:

        void setDelimiter(const char c) { m_delimiter = c;    }
        const char getDelimiter() const { return m_delimiter; }
    }
}
```

**Utilities.cpp**

```cpp
namespace sd {

    char Utilities::m_delimiter = ',';

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot call member function without object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127738/cannot-call-member-function-without-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call a normal member function on a object instance:

```
Utilities util;
util.setDelimiter(',');
```

In your case, maybe changing it to a static method?

```
static void setDelimiter(....)
```

Comment: static void setDelimiter() removed my compile error...
this is needed as one file use ',' and the other '|' as delimiter...
both are stored inside an array of one object type vector<Item> inventory