# Error with template specialization that relates to static members

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static

When I run the following piece of code,

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
enum class Fruit { apple, orange, pear };

template <typename T> struct Traits;

template <>
struct Traits<Fruit> {
    string name(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:return "apple";
        case 1: return "orange";
        case 2: return "pear";
        }
        return "unknown";
    }
};

int main()
{
    int t = 0; std::cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        int index1; std::cin >> index1;
        int index2; std::cin >> index2;
        cout << Traits<Fruit>::name(index2) << "\n";
    }
}
```

the error that I get is

```
Solution.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Solution.cpp:122:43: error: cannot call member function ‘std::__cxx11::string Traits<Color>::name(int)’ without object
         cout << Traits<Color>::name(index1) << " ";
```

which [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127738/cannot-call-member-function-without-object/1127772) that I don't have an object of the struct before calling a method of the struct. But if I add the keyword `static` in line 9, so that it becomes `static string name(int index){`, the code runs properly. Can someone help on what's causing this.

Comment: `name` is a non-static member function. It requires an object instance to be called on. If you add the keyword `static`, you make it a static member function, which doesn't require an object to be called on. This has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: @Nick the question has the answer. Thanks.

Comment: So as static variables are common for all objects of a class, they can directly be called through the class @IgorTandetnik ?