# Class function does not take arguments

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor

I am trying to simulate some plasma physics and for that I decided to create my "Simulation world" as a class, defined in "World.h" file:

```
#ifndef _WORLD_H
#define _WORLD_H

class World{
    public:
        World(int _Nx, double _x0, double _xf); //Constructor prototype
        
        int _Nx; //Number of nodes
        double _dx; //Cell width
        
        void setTime(double _dt, int _num_ts);
        
    protected:
        double _x0; //System origin
        double _xf; //System ending
        
        double _dt = 0;     //time step length
        int _num_ts;        //number of time steps
};

#endif
```

The implementation of the class prototypes goes:

```
#include "World.h"

World::World(int Nx, double x0, double xf)
{
    this->_Nx = Nx;
    this->_x0 = x0;
    this->_xf = xf;
    this->_dx = (xf - x0)/(Nx - 1);
    
    //std::cout << Nx;
}

void World::setTime(double dt, int num_ts)
{
    this->_dt=dt;
    this->_num_ts=num_ts;
 }
```

The problem I am having is that when I call the function "World::setTime(/**/)" from main:

```
int main()
{
    //Create computational system
    World world(1000, 0.0, 0.1); //(Nx, x0, xm)
    
    World::setTime(world._dx, 10000);

    /*CODE*/

    return 0;
}
```

the compiler shows the message:

> [Error] cannot call member function 'void World::setTime(double, int)' without object

Referring to the value of 'int num_ts' given as an argument. What is the prblem? What is the object it is referring to?

I was reading this post:

[cannot call member function without object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127738/cannot-call-member-function-without-object/1127772)

but I cannot apply the solution in there because I wrote down a constructor in my class. Thank you for your replies!

Comment: You shouldn't use underscore prefixes for public identifiers. Also, your naming convention is inconsistent between your header and your implementation.

Comment: Change `World::setTime(world._dx, 10000);` to `world.setTime( world._dx, 10000 );`

Comment: BTW, the `World::setTime(...)` syntax is meant for calling `static` methods or for resolving virtual members (as C++ doesn't have a `base`/`super` keyword).

Comment: `#define _WORLD_H` That name is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You should use another header guard. Also, the name of the parameter `int _Nx` is reserved for the same reason.

Comment: @Dai Thank you very much, it solved the problem. What do you mean by `base`/`super`?

Comment: @eerorika Thank you for your reply. If it is reserved, what is it reserved for? Is the problem in the underscore?

Comment: @AliEsquembreKucukalic `what is it reserved for?` for any purpose that the language implementation deems necessary. Typically, internal names of the standard library, language extensions etc. `Is the problem in the underscore?` Yes. Consult the language rules on reserved names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are calling member function of a **defined class** instead of an **object**. To fix that, I would try putting:

```
World world(1000,0.0,0.1); //(Nx,x0,xm)

world.setTime(world._dx, 10000);
```

This way you are calling an object that you have defined as "**world**" of type **World**.

Comment: The two colons (`::`) must also be changed to a single dot (`.`): `world.setTime`