# C++ roman numeral converter using class

Tags: c++

I am having issues with trying to figure out how to declare and call my functions. I had this working without using a class, but my assignment calls for a class, romanType, to be used. Can someone please help me figure out my issues?

Here are my errors:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "getRoman" is undefined  Garant_Project9 C:\Users\Andre\OneDrive\Desktop\C++\Garant_Project9\Garant_Project9\Garant_Project9.cpp 119

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6001   Using uninitialized memory 'sum'.   Garant_Project9 C:\Users\Andre\OneDrive\Desktop\C++\Garant_Project9\Garant_Project9\Garant_Project9.cpp 81

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'getRoman': identifier not found    Garant_Project9 C:\Users\Andre\OneDrive\Desktop\C++\Garant_Project9\Garant_Project9\Garant_Project9.cpp 119

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;


class romanType
{

public:
void printValue(char numeral[15]);
void Menu();
void getRoman();


private:

};

void romanType::printValue(char numeral[15])
{
int RomanValues[7] = { 1000,500,100,50,10,5,1 };
char Roman[7] = { 'M','D','C','L','X','V','I' };
int number = 0, ck[15] = { 0 }, len = 0;
bool ok = false;
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
    if (numeral[x] != '\0')
        len++; //Finding out how long the input is
    else
        x = 15;

for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
{
    ok = false;
    for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
    {
        if (numeral[x] == Roman[y])
            ok = true; // Making sure the input is all Roman numerals
    }
    if (!ok)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, the '" << numeral[x] << "' is NOT a Roman Numeral." << endl << "Try 
again.." << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
    {
        if (numeral[x] == Roman[y])
        {
            ck[x] = RomanValues[y];// Fill array ck with decimal value of inputted Roman #
        }
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
{
    if ((ck[x + 1] > ck[x]))
    {
        number += (ck[x + 1] - ck[x]); // If number is lower than next number, subtract
      // So IV is 4 and VI is 6
        x++;
    }
    else
        number += ck[x]; // else add
}
cout << number << endl << endl;
}


void romanType::Menu()
{
cout << "\tRoman Numeral Values" << endl << endl;
cout << "\t\tM = 1000" << endl;
cout << "\t\tD =  500" << endl;
cout << "\t\tC =  100" << endl;
cout << "\t\tL =   50" << endl;
cout << "\t\tX =   10" << endl;
cout << "\t\tV =    5" << endl;
cout << "\t\tI =    1" << endl;

}

void romanType::getRoman()
{
char numeral[15];

do
{
    Menu();
    cout << endl << "Please enter a Roman Numeral.\n(Enter 'Q', to end program)" << endl;
    cin >> numeral;
    for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
        numeral[x] = toupper(numeral[x]);
    if (numeral[0] == 'Q')
        cout << "Program terminating!" << endl;
    else
        printValue(numeral);
} while (numeral[0] != 'Q');
}

int main()
{
getRoman();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not satisfying the spirit of your assignment. You merely took a procedural approach to coding and slapped on a "class" label. Take some time to design your class. What is it's purpose? What data should it track? Why should a thing called `romanType` be responsible for deciding if your program should quit?

Comment: Also, you [cannot call a (non-static) member function without an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127738).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because an answer likely [would not be in the student's best interest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as a radically different design is called for.

Comment: Thank you - appreciate it. I have just learned about classes in an extremely short time and was confused about "objects" and I now see changes that I need to make. I am a very "visual" learner.